# How to implement search functionality in next js?

Tags: typescript, search, next.js, product

First of all, I am new to building websites so there will be mistakes in the code and any help is appreciated!!

So I want to implement the ability to search products on the website. I have done some work on the searchinput component. This is SearchInput component

```
"use client";

import { Search } from "lucide-react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useDebounce } from "use-debounce";

const SearchInput = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isSearchVisible, setIsSearchVisible] = useState(false);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [query] = useDebounce(searchQuery, 500);

  const pathname = usePathname();

  const onSearch = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const encodedSearchQuery = encodeURI(searchQuery);
    if (query) {
      router.push(`/?search=${query}`);
    } else {
      router.push("/");
    }
    console.log("query:", encodedSearchQuery);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (searchQuery.trim() !== "") {
  //     router.push(`/?search=${query}`);
  //   } else {
  //     // If searchQuery is empty, navigate back to the homepage
  //     router.push("/");
  //   }
  // }, [query, router]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSearch}>
      <div className="mr-4 relative  lg:flex hidden items-center text-gray-400 focus-within:text-gray-600">
        <button
          onClick={() => setIsSearchVisible(isSearchVisible)}
          className="absolute w-6 h-6 ml-4 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600"
        >
          <Search className="w-6 h-6" />
        </button>

        {(!isSearchVisible || pathname !== "/") && (
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            className="py-2 pl-12 px-4 rounded-full border border-indigo-200 hover:outline focus:border-blue-500"
            value={searchQuery}
            onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SearchInput;
```

I want to be able to display the query results that the user typed in the search input field.

This is the product card component that maps through all the products from a strapi database and displays them on the screen. I want the functionality so that it should display the filtered results from the query that the user typed.

ProductCard.tsx

```
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";

import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
import loadingimage from "../assets/loading.png";

type Props = {
  products: any[];
  searchQuery: string;
};

const myLoader = ({ src }: { src: string }) => {
  return `http://localhost:1337${src}`;
};

const ProductCard: React.FC<Props> = ({ products, searchQuery }) => {
  const initialProductCount = 15;
  const [visibleProducts, setVisibleProducts] = useState(initialProductCount);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const productArray = Object.values(products).reverse();
  const filteredProductArray = productArray.filter((product: any) =>
    product.attributes.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
  );

  const loadMoreProducts = () => {
    if (!loading && visibleProducts < productArray.length) {
      setLoading(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        const additionalProducts = 15;
        setVisibleProducts((prevCount) => prevCount + additionalProducts);
        setLoading(false);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >=
      document.documentElement.scrollHeight - 200
    ) {
      loadMoreProducts();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bg-white">
      <main className="mx-auto max-w-screen-lg px-6 py-20">
        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={visibleProducts}
          next={loadMoreProducts}
          hasMore={visibleProducts < productArray.length}
          loader={<p></p>}
          endMessage={<p></p>}
        >
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-custom lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 sm:gap-6">
            {filteredProductArray.slice(0, visibleProducts).map((product) => (
              <div
                key={product.id}
                className="border-1 shadow-md rounded-lg bg-white overflow-hidden max-w-[350px]  mx-auto"
              >
                <Head>
                  <title>{product?.attributes?.title}</title>
                  <meta
                    name="description"
                    content={product?.attributes?.description}
                  />
                  <meta
                    name="keywords"
                    content={product?.attributes?.keywords}
                  />
                </Head>
                <div className="object-cover">
                  <Link
                    href={product?.attributes?.link}
                    target="_blank"
                    className="object-cover"
                  >
                    <Image
                      className="rounded-t-lg w-full h-72"
                      loader={myLoader}
                      src={product?.attributes?.image?.data?.attributes?.url}
                      alt={product?.attributes?.title}
                      width={330}
                      height={275}
                    />
                  </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="p-3 text-left flex-grow">
                  <h3 className="font-semibold text-xl pb-3 text-gray-500">
                    {product?.attributes?.title}
                  </h3>
                  <p
                    className={`text-sm text-gray-700${
                      product?.attributes?.description?.length > 100
                        ? "line-clamp-5 text-gray-700"
                        : ""
                    }`}
                  >
                    {product?.attributes?.description}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div className="p-4 flex justify-between items-end">
                  <p className="text-lg font-bold">
                    &#8377;{product?.attributes?.price}
                  </p>
                  <Link href={product?.attributes?.link} target="_blank">
                    <button className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-lg">
                      Shop Now
                    </button>
                  </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
        {loading && (
          <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <Image
              src={loadingimage}
              alt="Loading image"
              width={50}
              height={50}
            ></Image>
          </div>
        )}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

How do I implement the functionality?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.